# Perl: Create a hash file using a loop

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, hash, reference

I import data from an XML-file and want to output the content into a log-file. Doing this I created for each entity a scalar (2). To output the entities with a loop I created a hash (3 and 4b) and with the for loop I output the name of the tag (entity) and the value (5). To get a specified order I use `Tie::IxHash`. Now, I wonder if I could avoid steps (3) and (4b) using a for loop. For example I could put the scalars `$x1`,`$x2` and `$x3` in an array and doing the steps (3) and (4b) with a loop. Is it possible?

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Tie::IxHash;

my $x1 = 'a';
my $x2 = '';
my $x3 = undef;  # no xml tag <x3>; 
 
# (3) Create a hash to output values in a log files using for
my $rx1 = \$x1;
my $rx2 = \$x2;
my $rx3 = \$x3;

# (4a) To make an ordered hash use Tie::IxHash
my %h;
tie %h, 'Tie::IxHash'; 
%h = ( 'x1' => $rx1
     , 'x2' => $rx2
     , 'x3' => $rx3);

# (4c) Output hash with undex content gives a warning 
print map { "$_ ${$h{$_}}\n" } keys %h;   # 51
# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 51. 

print "--------\n";
# (5) Output content of hash into a log file
print "using keys from hash:\n";
foreach my $k (keys %h)  {
    if ( not defined ${$h{$k}} or  ${$h{$k}} eq "" ) {${ $h{$k}} = undef; }
    if ( defined ${$h{$k}} ) { print "$k :  ${$h{$k}} \n";   } else {print  "$k :  undef\n"; }    
}
```

This gives the output:

```
# Output: 
# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 51.
# x1 a
# x2 
# x3 
# --------
# using keys from hash:
# x1 :  a 
# x2 :  undef
# x3 :  undef
```

### Update 1:

Thanks to Dave Cross I came up with this. It works for me.

```
#  Define hash [(step (1)-(4)]
%h = ( 'x1' => my $x1
     , 'x2' => my $x2
     , 'x3' => my $x3
     );

# import from xml
$h{x1} = 'a';
$h{x2} = '';
$h{x3} = undef;

# (5) Output content of hash into a log file
print "using keys from hash:\n";
foreach my $k (keys %h)  {
    if ( not defined $h{$k} or  $h{$k} eq "" )  { $h{$k} = undef; }
    if ( defined $h{$k} ) { print "$k :  $h{$k} \n";   } else {print  "$k :  undef\n"; }    
}
```

### Update 2

I simplified thanks to suggestions of choroba and Dave Cross. Now it is short and organized. I learned that you can assign data from interfaces directly into scalars which are within a hash or an array. Usually I like to declare scalar variables separatly but in this, if you have a myriad of variables it makes sense to write it only once into a hash or array and to declare the hash or array separatly.

```
#  Define hash [(step (1)-(4)]
%h = ( x1 => $xpc->findvalue('./X1',$node1)
     , x2 => $xpc->findvalue('./X2',$node1)
     , x3 => $xpc->findvalue('./X3',$node1)
     );

# (5) Output content of hash into a log file
print "using keys from hash:\n";
for my $k (keys %h)  {
    if ( not defined $h{$k} or  $h{$k} eq "" )  { $h{$k} = undef; }
    if ( defined $h{$k} ) { print "$k :  $h{$k} \n";   } else {print  "$k :  undef\n"; }    
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing references to scalars in your hash? Your code would be simpler if you stored the scalar values directly.

Comment: Why do you convert the x2 value from an empty string to `undef`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can assign the values directly to the hash keys. `tie my %h, 'Tie::IxHash'; %h = ( x1 => 'a', x2 = "", x3 => undef );`

Comment: @choroba Is this possible: `%h = ( x1 => $xpc->findvalue('./X1',$node1), x2 => $xpc->findvalue('./X2' ,$node1))`?

Comment: @Dave Cross. I don't distinguish between `undef` (Perl) and empty string. So, both will get the scalar value 'undef' which is output in the log. `undef` may occur when there is a missing entity. If I would not assign 'undef' there will be the warning: `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string`. I want to omit this warning.

Comment: @giordano: What happened when you tried?

Comment: If you converted `undef` to the empty string (rather than the other way round) then you wouldn't get the "uninitialized value" warning.

Comment: @Dave Cross: Good point. I could create directly `%h = ( 'x1' => my $x1,  'x2' => my $x2, 'x3' => my $x3);`. I didn't know that I can use `my` within a hash. I think, this could be the solution.

Comment: Er... that's really not going to do anything useful.

Comment: @Dave Cross Why? I implemented it (see update 1) and it works fine.

Comment: That's not what I suggested at all. You set the values in the hash to empty variables and then overwrite them with the actual values. So why set them to variables in the first place?

Comment: @choroba: I tried and it works, see update 2.

Comment: In "Update 2" you can simplify first `if` to `if ($h{$k} eq "")`, because there is no point in checking if it is undef and then setting it to undef. Also, the whole strategy of setting a value to the empty string to avoid warnings is a hack. You should fix it a proper way instead. Such as instead of `"$_ $h{$k}"` do `"$_ " . $h{$k} // "undef"`. `//` is the defined-or operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop can be made a bit simpler.

```
# To enable 'say()' - this is usually at the top of the file
use feature 'say';

for my $k (keys %h)  {
    $h{$k} = undef if defined $h{$k} and $h{$k} eq '';
    say "$k : ", $h{$k} // 'undef';
}
```

- Don't check for `undef` if you're going to set it to `undef`
- Use postfix conditions to make code easier to read
- Used the `//` (defined-or) operator in the print statement
- Use `say()` instead of `print()`

Comment: Postfix condition gives the warning: `Use of uninitialized value within %h in string eq at test.pl line 5.` (5th line in your code). Using the check with undef I can avoid the warning. I would prefer the postfix condition but I want avoid warnings. Thanks for defined-or operator. I didn't know it.

Comment: @giordano: Well, you can add the `defined()` check to the postfix version as well. See my update.